# javascript ampersand (&) in return data will not show as value

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I have this bit of code:

```
...
var aData = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('data')[0];
var sDescription = aData.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].firstChild.data;

alert(escape(sDescription));
document.getElementById('tempLabourLineDescription').value = sDescription;
...
```

sDescription is outputting: `SUPPORT ASSY-FUEL TANK MOUNTING, R&R (LH) (L-ENG)`

I think it is obvious what i want to do here (get the `sDescription` in to a field called `tempLabourLineDescription` but that just will not work.

However, if i in my php script replace or delete the &-char from that string it all works fine. So i thought, just escape the darn string. But that will just not work.
alerting the string doesn't work either until i remove the &-character.

What is doing this? Is sDescription not a string when it comes out of the xml file? 
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to tell without seeing your output script,  but the first thing to try is to mask the ampersand: `&amp;`

The neater way, though,  would be to add CDATA to your XML output:

```
<data><![CDATA[SUPPORT ASSY-FUEL TANK MOUNTING, R&R (LH) (L-ENG)]]></data>
```

your XML parser on client side should understand it no problem.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that. Never occured to me that & is not valid XML. CDATA did it all. javascript ate it without a problem and without escaping.

Comment: Nice! It also makes it possible to use `<` and `>` without having to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in this snippet:

```
var aData = request.responseXML...
```

You're expecting XML.  An & by itself is not legal XML.  You need to output your result like this:

> SUPPORT ASSY-FUEL TANK MOUNTING, R&amp;R (LH) (L-ENG)

Answer (score 0):

You escape the ampersand by using the HTML eqv. `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to alter the XML output from the server (it's not your app or some other issue), a "hack" fix would be:

```
function htmlizeAmps(s){
  return s.replace(/\x26/g,"&amp;"); //globalreplace "&" (hex 26) with "&amp;"
}
document.getElementById('tempLabourLineDescription').value = htmlizeAmps(sDescription);
```